# Unity crashes on iOS from BaseBoard

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash

I am seeing many crashes on my Unity game on iOS, and when looking at the crash report, I see the cause as BaseBoard.

Here is a snapshot from the xCode organizer:
[image]

Can anyone point in some direction what might cause this? I don't recognize any of my code there..

What is BaseBoard class?

Comment: Are you using any components in your app that sound like they might have used something like it, for example http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CreateTerrainBaseboards

Comment: No, but after more checking, it seems that BaseBoard is related to a virtual keyboard? https://cocoapods.org/pods/BaseBoard Can anyone confirm?

Comment: On second thought, it seems that BaseBoard is private internal iOS framework: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework?